# Column Width autofit functionality using perl

Tags: perl, excel, ole

I have generated the excel sheet using set of csv files using perl script.In that i need to set width of the column as **auto-fit**.What 'm suppose to do i've got The way to do this in the module called OLE i don't know how to do this you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to set a file's column to "AutoFit" because that is not a setting of the file.  Excel calculates this and sets a column width at run-time.

One option is to calculate the "AutoFit" width yourself based on your data, and then set the column width to the value that you calculate.
[This discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/spreadsheet-writeexcel/6XZBtM3mS5M) gives some workaround code that does that.

Another option is to [use `Win32::OLE`](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1709/lib/Win32/OLE.pm) to set the column to AutoFit.  How to do this is not documented in the module itself; you would have to search around the Microsoft OLE documentation to find the appropriate command.

**Update:** [This site](http://www.ngbdigital.com/perl_ole_excel.html) appears to show how to use AutoFit with `Win32::OLE`.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate your Excel file with [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Excel%3a%3aWriter%3a%3aXLSX) module, and adjust the column width with [set_column](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.65/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm#set_column%28_%24first_col,_%24last_col,_%24width,_%24format,_%24hidden,_%24level,_%24collapsed_%29) method

Comment: what I said was true, I didn't write about "AutoFit"

Comment: ya exactly...for making auto fit is quite lengthy by manually

Comment: @MiguelPrz, ok, but the question was specifically about AutoFit.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the autofit.pl example [here](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel/Examples.pm#Example%3a_autofit.pl)